# Moderncv - Align dates with linebreaks

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am writing my CV with LaTeX, using moderncv. Dates that are longer (eg. 03/2021-08/2023) are causing a linebreak. I am fine with the linebreak, but I would like to have the two lines to be aligned such that either the months are left aligned or the years right aligned (with the hyphen moved to the second line).

MWE:

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,german]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{orange}                             
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            personal data
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{NAME}
\title{}                               
\address{Street 123}{12344 City}{Country}       
\mobile{+12 3456789012}                          
\email{email.email@email.com}
\photo[96pt][0pt]{example-image-a}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{-20mm}
    \makecvtitle
    \vspace*{-12mm}
    \section{Education}
        \cventry{since 10/20xx}{M.A XY}{University of XY}{}{Grade: Y.Y}{Focus: Subject, Thesis: This is my thesis title}
        \cventry{10/20xx -- 09/20xx}{B.A XY}{University of XY}{}{Grade: Y.Y}{Focus: Subject, Thesis: Thesis: This is my thesis title}
        \cventry{09/20xx -- 07/20xx}{Higher Education Entrance Qualification (A-levels)}{School}{}{}{}
        \vspace*{-3mm}

    \section{Working Experience}
    \cventry{10/20xx -- 03/20xx}{Intern}{Company}{Division}{}{Here comes a list of my tasks}    
    \cventry{10/20xx -- 03/20xx}{Research Assistant}{Chair for XY}{}{}{Here comes a list of my tasks}
    \cventry{09/20xx -- 12/20xx}{Intern}{Company}{}{}{Here comes a list of my taks}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the output generated from my MWE]

I think the best would be to left-align all months/years such that they form a line with "since 20xx"

**Edit**: The use of `\vspace*{-3mm}` helps me to put all my information on one page. Therefore, I would like not to change the width of the columns as currently everything fits perfectly - except the alignment of the dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to add `\\` where a line break is desired. For example, replace `10/20xx -- 09/20xx` with `10/20xx\\-- 09/20xx`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This simple adjustment did the trick. I deleted my earlier comment where I hinted towards a new problem arising from this solution since it had nothing to do with it (I removed a % which resulted in chaos and I simply did not see it...)